# Bhagavad Gita by Lord Krishna

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

During the Kurukshetra war, Shri Krishna recited the holy Gita to Arjuna. My question is, why did he choose to do that only to Arjuna and not to the other Pandavas?